# Any similar idioms to "Don't blow your own horn/trumpet"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, proverbs, proverb-requests

I am looking for idioms in English which convey a message that a person should not testify about his own character.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does “Don't blow your own horn/trumpet” not have that you're looking for?

Comment: The "blow your own horn" idiom refers to boasting rather than testimony. That is, it means "don't be a braggart." To "testify about his own character" has lots of shades. For example, do you mean to imply you don't believe somebody making claims about their own character? That gets into "the lady doth protest too much." Which you should look up.

Comment: There is "give oneself a pat on the back" but that isn't boasting or testifying, so I won't make it an answer.

Comment: Not really an idiom, but there is also the Bible verse John 5 v 31-32 (where I believe Jesus is, in the first of those two verses, quoting or paraphrasing, Jewish law).

Comment: It's not an idiom, but "conflict of interest" is an official phrase indicating that someone can't be objective about something that concerns them closely. The use is broader than what you suggest; yes, I have a "conflict of interest" in assessing myself, but also in assessing my friends or family.

Comment: If you grew up in modern era in the US, "don't toot your own horn" is by far the more common way to express this.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't sing your own praises**

> **To sing the praises of**
> Express enthusiastic approval or admiration of (someone or something)
> *Uncle Felix never stopped singing her praises* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sing_the_praises_of)

> **Sing someone's/something's praises** (idiom)
> To say good things about someone or something often in a very enthusiastic way
> *The doctor has a wonderful bedside manner and patients sing her praises.*  [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sing%20someone%27s%20praises)

---

> Self-praise is no recommendation. A man's praise smells sweet when it
> comes out of other men's mouths, but in his own it stinks. Grow your
> own cherries, but **don't sing your own praises.** [G. H. Spurgeon;
> *John Ploughman's Talk; Or, Plain Advice for Plain People*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/John_Ploughman_s_Talk_Or_Plain_Advice_fo/UixcAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=don%27t%20sing%20your%20own%20praises&pg=PA147&printsec=frontcover) (1886)

> **"Don't sing your own praises**; let someone else do it.” With that last bit of advice, we departed to pick up Miss Brown and set off on
> our journey. [Errol St. John Stephenson; *Roots Radical*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Roots_Radical/lUmLGbqIFc4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=sing%20your%20own)

> **Don't sing your own praises**, this will come across as arrogant and will alienate people. Instead let others do it for you, while you
> remain modest and humble. [Chris Batten; *Making Rain*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Making_Rain/42C-DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=don%27t%20sing%20your%20own%20praises&pg=PT146&printsec=frontcover)